# Row returned by a query with ROWNUM and PRIMARY KEY column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm reading about 1 of the oracle pseudocolumns i.e 
**ROWNUM**: which return number indicating the order in which oracle return the row.

I have encountered some behavior here,

Example  used
1. Create Script:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2),       
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

2 Insert Script:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)
VALUES (2, 'Max', 22, 'India', 4500.00 );

INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)
VALUES (1, 'Maths', 22, 'US', 4500.00 );
```

select * from CUSTOMERS; executed in the same order as inserted above,

```
ID      NAME AGE ADDRESS SALARY 
------  ---- --- ------- ------
2       Max  22  India  4500.00

1       Math 22  US     4500.00
```

Here if I run the select query,

```
select 
rownum,
customers.ID
from customers;
```

I get below output:

```
ROWNUW  ID
------  --
1       1

2       2
```

Here **ID = 2** is inserted **first** but oracle returns in the 2nd row,

But if you include any other column from a table with ROWNUM and PK like

```
select 
rownum,
customers.ID,customers.Name
from customers;
```

I get correct output (Correct inserted order) :

```
ROWNUW  ID NAME
------  -- ----
1       2  Max

2       1  Math
```

If run query without Name column i.e only **ROWNUW** (pseudocolumns) and **PK** (table column)

We get this,

```
ROWNUW  ID
------  --
1       1

2       2
```

My Question is Why is that **ID=2** is not first returned row.

if I query **any** table **column** with **ROWNUM**, I get the result back based on insertion order.

Example below

```
select 
    rownum,
(NAME / AGE  / ADDRESS  SALARY) any one of these columns
From CUSTOMERS
```

But if use **ROWNUM** with **ID** (Primary Key column) insertion order is not working. why is this behavior with the only Primary Key column?

Comment: "I get correct output (Correct inserted order)". Oracle does not keep track of insertion order. If that is important for you, you need to add a column for it and order by that.

Comment: @Thilo if I query any table column with ROWNUM, I get the result back based on insertion order. but if use ROWNUM with PK insertion order is not working

Comment: No you don't. If you do not specify an ORDER BY, there is no defined order in the result set. The database will return them in whatever order is most convenient.

Answer (score 1):

ROWNUM values depends on how oracle access the resultset. Once resultset is fetched, `rownum` is assigned to the rows.

As there is no guarantee in what order the data is returned, there is no guarantee in what order `rownum` is assigned.

Maybe if you try running both of your queries without rownum, you might get the rows swapped as you showed, or they might not.

Comment: There is also no guarantee that the rows are stored on disk in any kind of order. In particular insertion order is not necessarily preserved. So even if ROWNUM gave you the physical storage order (which, as you point out, it does not), that would not be very useful either.

Answer (score 0):

Rownum will always be in order of 1,2,3,4 .. no matter what you are getting in result set. It is always calculated after result set is returned from query.

Now, you have ID column as PRIMARY KEY which makes it eligible for default clustered index creation in database. So when you select only PRIMARY column, it will be sorted as it was stored in DB that way. Index created as a result of PRIMARY key creation is sorted in ASC which is default.

Here if you select only PRIMARY KEY column i.e. "ID", Database is returning it in sorted order and ROWNUM is writing 1 & 2 to it.

But if you are selecting some extra non-PRIMARY KEY as well then it is totally upto oracle, whichever way it finds data faster. Sometimes it will return data from cache memory. If not it will read disk and fetch data. While reading datafile, there are multiple things which will differ machine to machine i.e is your table partitioned? is your table sharing tablespace ? what organization you are using in table ? blah blah....

Bottom line is, don't trust ROWNUM. It gives 1,2,3.. after you have applied your brain to the query.